# Android ZXing image processing

Tags: android, image-processing, matrix, zxing

I have to scan a Data Matrix written on something like [this](http://www.google.ro/imgres?imgurl=http://www.okokchina.com/Files/uppic18/Hologram%2520sticker%2520for%2520security_Hologram%2520film405.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.okokchina.com/product/Office-Supply/Paper-Packaging/Coated-Paper/index_3.htm&usg=__yGNA5UbshM_TiQYL6-fLapPA1go=&h=1704&w=2272&sz=1696&hl=ro&start=160&zoom=1&tbnid=GTmenTLC2ituTM%3a&tbnh=151&tbnw=201&ei=E-YaTvaONs-08QOllq0v&prev=/search?q=hologram&um=1&hl=ro&sa=N&biw=1280&bih=850&tbm=isch&um=1&itbs=1&iact=rc&dur=278&page=9&ndsp=20&ved=1t:429,r:11,s:160&tx=106&ty=50&biw=1280&bih=850). 
The code is white/light gray but the background reflects different colors, depending on the position of the camera(angle), light.
Where would be the right place to edit the image captured in Android Zxing?
Is there any possible adjustment to make the image black on white before processing?

Any idea would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
            cm.setSaturation(0);
            ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
            paint.setColorFilter(f);
            int xo = (w-500)/2;
            int yo = (h-500)/2;
            c.drawBitmap(bmp, -xo, -yo, paint);
            bmp.recycle();
```

Comment: This would go in the Capture Activity?

Comment: mmmm I see. this code will create the black/white picture right?

Comment: I want to process the image before it goes to decoding. Is there a better approach?

Comment: before decoding there is no image! no pixels! it is impossible to manipulate the image before decoding ): sorry

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to preprocess the image in Android, where you are stuck with `CameraManager.buildLuminanceSource`. However, it is possible with JavaME and JavaSE. An alternative may be uploading the image to a server, where you can use `BufferedImageLuminanceSource(java.awt.image.BufferedImage image)`.

Answer (score 2):

Also have a look at this class:

http://zxing.org/w/docs/javadoc/com/google/zxing/common/HybridBinarizer.html

Maybe you are using by default the `GlobalHistogramBinarizer`, which is faster but doesn't work so good with gradients.

Comment: I use :`PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = CameraManager.get().buildLuminanceSource(data, width, height);
    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));` so the **HybridBinarizer**.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need some image processing before recognition. Previous answer suggest histogram bianrizer,  which is sensitive  to background intensity changes.  Sauvola filter is known to have good tolerance to background changes ( and gradients),  but has higher processing time. 
( Implemented in our OCR Project: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/ , and you can see it in action
in this application: https://market.android.com/details?id=de.pribluda.android.ocrcall&feature=search_result )